# zIndex is not refeshing as result of state change

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I managed to work this out, and setup 3 cards one on top of the other as seperate boxs compose elements with onclick and on drag properties.
The issue is now, that I'd like the card that I'm pressing/dragging to set to the front, so, I played with the z-index modifier, but, it looks like I'm doing something wrong. Any idea?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Test1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {

                    for (i in 1 until 4) {
                        DraggableBox(title = "Box_${+1}", initX = 100f*i.toFloat(), initY = 100f, content =
                        {
                            Text(text = "Box_${i}", color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                        }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DraggableBox(title: String, initX: Float = 0f, initY: Float = 0f, content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
    val cardInitWidth = 135f
    val cardInitHeight = 190f
    val expandValue = 20f

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val enable = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        var offsetX  =  remember { Animatable(initialValue = initX) }
        var offsetY  =  remember { Animatable(initialValue = initY) }
        val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        val clickable = Modifier.clickable(
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = LocalIndication.current
        ) { }
        val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
        val size = animateSizeAsState(
            targetValue = if (enable.value && !isPressed) {
                Size(width = cardInitWidth, height = cardInitHeight)
            } else {
                Size(width = cardInitWidth + expandValue, height = cardInitHeight + expandValue)
            }
        )
        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(
                        x = offsetX.value.roundToInt(),
                        y = offsetY.value.roundToInt()
                    )
                }
                .zIndex(zIndex = if (enable.value && !isPressed) 5f else 0f)
                .size(size.value.width.dp, size.value.height.dp)
                .clip(shape)
                //.background(Color(0xFF5FA777))
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Black), shape = shape)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = {
                            enable.value = !enable.value
                        },
                        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consumeAllChanges()
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                offsetX.snapTo(targetValue = offsetX.value + dragAmount.x)
                                offsetY.snapTo(targetValue = offsetY.value + dragAmount.y)
                            }
                            spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessHigh, visibilityThreshold = 0.1.dp)

                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            enable.value = !enable.value
                            spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow, visibilityThreshold = 0.1.dp)
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                launch {
                                    offsetY.animateTo(
                                        targetValue = initY,
                                        animationSpec = tween(
                                            durationMillis = 700,
                                            delayMillis = 50,
                                            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                                offsetX.animateTo(
                                    targetValue = initX,
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        durationMillis = 700,
                                        delayMillis = 50,
                                        easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                .then(clickable)
        ) {
            Row  (modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            )
            {
                Column (modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                )
                {
                    Column (
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    )
                    {
                        Text(text = "init-X: ${initX.toString()}", color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                        Text(text = "init-Y: ${initY.toString()}", color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                    }
                    Column (
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    )
                    {
                        Text(text = "offset-X: ${offsetX.value.roundToInt().toString()}", color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                        Text(text = "offset-Y: ${offsetY.value.roundToInt().toString()}", color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                    }
                    Column (
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    )
                    {
                        content()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Modifier.zIndex` works only for children within the same parent.

In your case you should move this modifier to the topmost `Box`. To do so you have to move `enable` and `isPressed` one level up too, and I would move all the other variables as well - but that's just a matter of taste, I guess.

```
val enable = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState() 

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .zIndex(zIndex = if (enable.value && !isPressed) 5f else 0f)
) {
    // ...
```

Comment: That works as charm!
So... The Modifier.zIndex works only for children within the same parent., how come it doesn't work on the Box inside that previous Box, looking at it as the 'new' parent?

Comment: @Joe top `Box` only has one child, in this case it doesn't matter what zIndex this child has. Or may be I didn't get your question here

Comment: I think I realised this now after playing around for hours. So... is there a way to expose that zIndex to other componenst? lets say, I click one of those, and I want to move it to the highest most zIndex, how can I know what is the highest without query the other components (other boxs)?

Comment: @Joe usually you just update zindex for all items in the list